# MySQL and MariaDB - casting a string representing decimal value with many leading zeros into numeric value gives an unexpected result

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When casting a string representing decimal value with many leading zeros into numeric value MySQL and MariaDB gives an unexpected result - with enabled strict mode `Out of range value` error happens, and with disabled strict mode `Out of range value` warning is shown and the result is clamped to maximal decimal value with given precision.
For example:

`SELECT CAST(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020.01 AS DECIMAL(15,2)) as val;` gives `9999999999999.99`

But actually it is not value that is out of range, it is just value with many leading zeros! Why it work like this? In `MS SQL` and `PostgreSQL` this doesn't happen

Comment: If you have already reported this to Oracle, and got an answer from Oracle, I am not sure what you are expecting this community to add to the situation, unless you are trying to raise an angry mob with pitch forks and torches to storm the Castle and burn the monster

Comment: I've put this here just in order to have the information and warning about this issue in an easy searchable place

Comment: If you did not put it here, google would still find "casting a string representing decimal value with many leading zeros into numeric value gives an unexpected result" . That's you MariaDB bug report,  which would be the first hit, if you did not cross-post here.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub, IMHO presently the most developers facing an issue prefer firstly look for it at SO and then dig into specific sources to get more details

Comment: but alright, Oracle MySQL bug is not searchable. They made it private, and really I do not mind the  SO entry staying there, as reminder  that Oracle MySQL hides bugs, even if they classify them as non-bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we came into it we investigated this behaviour, the bug happens with disabled strict mode when input string is longer than 83 symbols. `83` limit is related to the `DECIMAL_MAX_STR_LENGTH` constant in `MySQL` `C` source code, when input string is longer than that constant, the resulted value is set to maximal decimal value with given precision.
The bug is present in `MySQL 8.0` and in `MariaDB 10.4.13` and maybe in theirs older versions also.

This could be dangerous in some cases, for example in online financial services that use MySQL. A malicious persons could use this bug for getting big amount of money on its account by entering sum with many leading zeros.

We [reported](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100128) this bug to `MySQL` developers, they answered that it is

> a known behaviour. Simply, digital data type has its limit. This
> particular limit is not too well described, in particular the part of
> whet happens if you make an overflow.

They decided not to fix this, but added its description into their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-expressions.html).

Also we [reported](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23105) to `MariaDB`, and they have fixed the issue